# Displaying an image in web browser using get vs post

Tags: http, post, get

While reading about jsp/servlet technology (more specifically `get` and `post` methods) I found some limitations of the `get` method -

- We can send less data with the `get` method compared to the `post` method.
- `get` method only supports character data while the `post` method supports binary data. So I think I can send an image to a server using the `post` method.
- Generally the `get` method is used to get some data from the server/database.

If the `get` method doesn't support binary data and get method usually used to receive data from server/database how are the images/video file displayed in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to get into the differences from `GET` and `POST`, there are plenty of good resources on the web for that.  I do think you're confused about how `GET` works.

> `GET` is used to **request** information from a server.  It has nothing to do with what type of data is returned.  The server can return anything it's designed to return.(i.e. images, etc) .  Think of `GET` as a URL request.  You pass a querystring in a URL, which is information you want to send the server.
>
> You could theoretically send the server a file, but you can't pass binary data in a URL unless you [base64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) encode it. (which turns the binary into characters)  You would normally want to use `POST` for something like that.